# App crash after the execution all code

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I make programm, parse JSON text and output to ListView, but the app crash after the execution all code, why?

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Make app");

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<String> listIdJson = idJsonList();  //get ArrayList          

        Log.d(TAG, "oN1");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_main, listIdJson);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d(TAG, "oN exit");

    }
```

Log output:

```
03-04 06:30:50.056    1484-1484/ru.vlad.pbj D/myLogs﹕ Make app
03-04 06:30:51.826    1484-1484/ru.vlad.pbj D/myLogs﹕ oN1
03-04 06:30:51.826    1484-1484/ru.vlad.pbj D/myLogs﹕ oN exit
```

Comment: Any exception in logcat?

Comment: Why you set `activity_main` layout in `adapter` here `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main, listIdJson);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the same layout to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_main, listIdJson);
```

Comment: @Vlad161 :) np, happens sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_main, listIdJson);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listIdJson);
```

For more information to go: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set content view for Array Adapter you may change it as follows.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listIdJson);
```